# Ulimit file descriptor limits not being applied for particular process

Tags: linux, debian, ulimit

I recently checked one of our redis processes to what ulimits where applied using:

`cat /proc/<redis-pid>/limits`

And was suprised to learn that is was at the low default value:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           
Max open files            4016                 4016
```

I was suprised, because we have the following configured:

```
# /etc/sysctl.conf 
fs.file-max = 100000
```

.

```
# /etc/security/limits.conf
* soft nofile 100000
* hard nofile 100000
```

.

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
UsePAM yes
```

.

```
# /etc/pam.d/sshd
session required pam_limits.so
```

**Can anyone tell me why the increased ulimit is not being applied to the running redis process?**

The redis process is running as the user 'redis', the server has been rebooted since the limits were increased. We are on Debian Squeeze.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Linux resource limits can be set in various locations based on the type of requirement.

1. `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.
2. `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.
3. `ulimit` command

`/etc/security/limits.conf` is part of [pam_limits](https://wiki.debian.org/Limits) and so the limits that are set in this file is read by pam_limits module during login sessions. The login session can be by `ssh` or through `terminal`. And pam_limits will not affect the daemon processes as mentioned [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Limits).

`/etc/sysctl.conf` is a system wide global configuration, we cannot set user specific configuration here. It sets the maximum amount of resource that can be used by all users/processes put to gether.

`ulimit` command is used to set the limits of the shell. And so when a limit is set with `ulimit` on a shell, the process which gets spawned from the shell gets that value too because of the rule that the `child process` inherits the `parent processes` properties.

And so for your case, as the `redis` is started as part of `init` none of the above will help you directly. The proper way of doing this is that, you have to use the `ulimit` command to set the new value in the init script itself. Like below in the script,

```
ulimit -n 100000
if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid redis:redis --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS.
```

There is already a [bug filed in wishlist](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=302079) to add `ulimit` feature to `start-stop-daemon`
.

Also check in `redis` configuration if there is any way of providing limits there.

Comment: Great summary Kannan!  I've now gone ahead and added the ulimit to the startup script.  It's a pity there is no way of just setting the limit for the user which will work with deamonised processes (as we have multiple startup scripts), but this works.  Thank you!

Comment: Great answer. The child process inheriting the parent process's properties was what surprised me, the limits all looked correct for the user running the child process but it was the limit from the owner of the parent process which was being used.

Answer (score 2):

The sysctl fs.file-max parameter is wide global system limit, i don't think is a good idea setting in ulimit the same value.

If you set in ulimit 100000 and in sysctl.conf 100000 too, one user can block the system

Any way, talking about your problem, you neet to be sure, your system use pam_limits

```
man pam_limits
grep -i limit /etc/pam.d/*
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll consider raising the fs.file-max value then.  Regarding pam - I believe we are using this (I've added some extra config to the question).  I'm not really sure I understand PAM though, as our settings seem to be relate to SSH, which is not used by this user.  Is there any other file I need to configure?  I could always put a ulimit setting in the init scripts for redis, but would rather not have to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You've enabled pam_limits for sshd, but is this command being executed from an SSH session? You may need to add the same line to `/etc/pam.d/login` and/or `/etc/pam.d/su` and/or `/etc/pam.d/sudo`.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that wasn't quite right. The process is being started this line in an init.d script : `if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid redis:redis --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS`. Which pam would be appropriate in this case?

Comment: in your script you can use ulimit -n 100000

Comment: Does the init.d script use a `su [user] -c` command to start the script as another user, or does your program run as root? If it's using `su`, then you'd put it in `/etc/pam.d/su`. If you're running as `root`, you're probably better off with c4f4t0r's suggestion of adding the `ulimit` command in your init script. `root` is allowed to set any limits it wants, so you don't really need to worry about pam for that case.

Comment: Thanks. It uses `--chuid redis:redis` on `start-stop-daemon`.  I've added the ulimit to the startup script now.