# Linux - Open file inheritance

Tags: linux-kernel, ulimit

For testing, I've changed my global open file limit to 3000:

```
#sysctl -w fs.file-max=3000
fs.file-max = 3000

#cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
2016    0       3000
```

I've created some files:

```
 i=1; while [ "$i" -le 1000  ]; do : >> "$i"; i=$(($i + 1)); done
```

I've held them open:

```
i=1; while [ "$i" -le 1000  ]; do less  "$i" & ; i=$(($i + 1)); done
```

I've seen the chaos I just created:

```
ksh: /bin/less: cannot execute [Too many open files in system]
```

I know I hit the limit....

```
# cat  /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
3008    0       3000
```

If I now raise the open file limit up (so I can ssh in using another console) and if I check on one of the recent less's I spawned after setting the open file max to 3000, I see:

```
# cat /proc/28282/limits  | grep 'Max open files'
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit       Units
Max open files            1024                 16384            files
```

The "Hard limit" is still set high, though no mention of 3000. 
So we hit the system limit, not the per process limit.

Why would'nt a newly created process be instructed to inherit 3000 vs 16384?

I logg'ed in in a new terminal with a new shell, so why wouldn't my shell be told 3000 and pass that down to less?

This is a 2.6.32 kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this link [Ulimit file descriptor limits not being applied for particular process](https://serverfault.com/questions/641899/ulimit-file-descriptor-limits-not-being-applied-for-particular-process)

I quote:

"/etc/security/limits.conf is part of pam_limits and so the limits that are set in this file is read by pam_limits module during login sessions. The login session can be by ssh or through terminal"

/etc/sysctl.conf is a system wide global configuration, we cannot set user specific configuration here. It sets the maximum amount of resource that can be used by all users/processes put together"

/etc/sysctl.conf is not the right place for setting this.

I would need  to fully investigate /etc/security/limits.conf and "pam_limits"