# Add LimitNOFILE on haproxy init script

Tags: security, haproxy, ulimit, limits

I want to add open files limit to HAProxy 1.8 process to 1024576. But since I use version 1.8, I cannot add LimitNOFILE to init scripts, instead of systemd file. How can I add limitNOFILE to those processes ?

*P.S: I had changed openfile on `/etc/security/limits.conf`, `/etc/security/limits.d/20-nbproc.conf` and also set `ulimit -n` to 1024576 and `sysctl -p fs.file-max=1024576`. But when I do "`cat /proc/{pid}/limits`", the open files still 4096.

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense enough to help. Are you using systemd or not?

Comment: No. I'm using init.d

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the init script and use `ulimit` to increase the limit along with making the sysctl changes permanently. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/642082/255125) for why changing `limits.conf` won't work.